# How to update date field ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table called Rateplan and the data looks like this :

For example :

```
SELECT Rateplanid
    , listingid
    , rentalunitid
    , validfromdate
    , validtodate
FROM Rateplan
WHERE listingid = 721760
    AND rentalunitid = 3027217
ORDER BY 
      listingid
    , rentalunitid
    , validfromdate
    , validtodate

 Rateplanid  listingid  rentalunitid    validfromdate             validtodate
    3        721760     3027217         2012-08-09 00:00:00.000   2012-10-18 00:00:00.000
  22563      721760     3027217         2012-10-26 00:00:00.000   2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
  25412      721760     3027217         2012-10-30 00:00:00.000   2012-10-30 00:00:00.000
  25421      721760     3027217         2012-10-31 00:00:00.000   2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
  26945      721760     3027217         2012-11-01 00:00:00.000   2012-11-07 00:00:00.000
  34807      721760     3027217         2012-11-14 00:00:00.000   2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
  35947      721760     3027217         2012-11-15 00:00:00.000   2012-11-15 00:00:00.000
  43793      721760     3027217         2012-11-29 00:00:00.000   2013-01-03 00:00:00.000
  62665      721760     3027217         2013-01-03 00:00:00.000   2199-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Logic is Validtodate in a current row need to be updated based on Validfromdate of Next row.
 If ValidfromDate of nextrow is <= Validtodate of current row ,then it need to be updated as one day less than that ValisfromDate of next rows value. 
But we also need to make sure the updated Validtodate need to be less than or equal to validfromdate of current row .

expected OUTPUT:

```
Rateplanid  listingid  rentalunitid    validfromdate             validtodate
    3        721760     3027217         2012-08-09 00:00:00.000   2012-10-18 00:00:00.000
  22563      721760     3027217         2012-10-26 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000
  25412      721760     3027217         2012-10-30 00:00:00.000   2012-10-30 00:00:00.000
  25421      721760     3027217         2012-10-31 00:00:00.000   2012-10-31 00:00:00.000
  26945      721760     3027217         2012-11-01 00:00:00.000   2012-11-07 00:00:00.000
  34807      721760     3027217         2012-11-14 00:00:00.000   2012-11-14 00:00:00.000
  35947      721760     3027217         2012-11-15 00:00:00.000   2012-11-15 00:00:00.000
  43793      721760     3027217         2012-11-29 00:00:00.000   2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
  62665      721760     3027217         2013-01-03 00:00:00.000   2199-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Does Rateplan table contain primary key?

Comment: @zxspectrum yes I have added Rateplaid primary key to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @tmptable as table (listingid int, rentalunitid int, validfromdate datetime, processed int)
DECLARE @listingid as int
DECLARE @rentalunitid as int
DECLARE @validtodate as date
DECLARE @validfromdate as date
DECLARE @validtodatenew as date

set @listingid = 721760
set @rentalunitid = 3027217

INSERT INTO @tmptable
SELECT
      listingid
    , rentalunitid
    , validfromdate
    , 0 as processed
FROM Rateplan
WHERE listingid = @listingid
    AND rentalunitid = @rentalunitid

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) from @tmptable where processed = 0) > 0
BEGIN

SET @validtodate = (SELECT top 1 validtodate from @tmptable where processed = 0)
SET @validfromdate = (SELECT TOP 1 validfromdate from @tmptable where processed = 0 and validtodate = @validtodate)

SET @validtodatenew = (SELECT top 1 validfromdate from Rateplan where listingid = @listingid and rentalunitid = @rentalunitid and validfromdate > @validtodate order by validfromdate asc)

UPDATE rateplan
SET validtodate = DATEADD(day,-1,@validtodatenew)
WHERE listingid = @listingid and rentalunitid = @rentalunitid and validtodate = @validtodate and validfromdate = @validfromdate

UPDATE @tmptable
SET processed = 1
WHERE listingid = @listingid and rentalunitid = @rentalunitid and validtodate = @validtodate and validfromdate = @validfromdate
and processed = 0

CONTINUE
END
```

**IF you have a primary key on this table, it would be so much easier and less error prone. I'll use pkey as the primary key in this example.**

```
DECLARE @tmptable as table (pkey int, validfromdate datetime, processed int)
DECLARE @listingid as int
DECLARE @rentalunitid as int
DECLARE @validtodatenew as date

set @listingid = 721760
set @rentalunitid = 3027217

INSERT INTO @tmptable
SELECT
    , pkey
    , validfromdate
    , 0 as processed
FROM Rateplan
WHERE listingid = @listingid
    AND rentalunitid = @rentalunitid

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) from @tmptable where processed = 0) > 0
BEGIN

SET @pkey = (Select top 1 pkey from @tmptable where processed = 0)

SET @validfromdate = (Select validfromdate from @tmptable where pkey = @pkey)

SET @validtodatenew = (SELECT top 1 validfromdate from Rateplan where listingid = @listingid and rentalunitid = @rentalunitid and validfromdate > @validfromdate order by validfromdate asc)

UPDATE rateplan
SET validtodate = DATEADD(day,-1,@validtodatenew)
WHERE pkey = @pkey

UPDATE @tmptable
SET processed = 1
WHERE pkey = @pkey and processed = 0

CONTINUE
END
```

Edit: Realized I was adding a date rather than subtracting a date.

Comment: and I assume you changed pkey to Rateplanid? What is your outcome? Please let me know if it was a simple syntax issue or it changed the wrong field.

Comment: yes i changed the pkey to rateplanid. The output is no way close to the one i want

Comment: Hey Peter, I just realized I was adding a date and not subtracting the date. I totally understand your request. I'm sorry I am unable to come up with a solution in the first attempt. if you could provide more information about what the output you recieved, I would be happy to make more adjustments.

Comment: The answer which you provided is just subtracting validtodate from validfromdate but my Logic is Validtodate in a current row need to be updated based on Validfromdate of Next row. If ValidfromDate of nextrow is <= Validtodate of current row ,then it need to be updated as one day less than that ValisfromDate of next rows value. But we also need to make sure the updated Validtodate need to be less than or equal to validfromdate of current row